# How could one create Google-Suggest style search suggestions with Javascript/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, google-suggest

How could one create Google-Suggest style search suggestions with Javascript/AJAX? References to articles would be much appreciated.

I would like to retrieve the "suggestions" from a database. (Essentially just a list of keywords)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Is it [Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's very useful! It looks like this plugin however has been superseded: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/